# Exact Orientation (Left or Right) on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, orientation

I know

```
Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
```

but is there a way to distinguish whether the device is turned left or right. I need a kind of spirit level and depending on whether the device is turned to the left or right, I have to reverse the axis.

Of course I can read the sensors but since its possible to look the orientation on some devices this results in very strange behavior.